# os.execute start is only giving the browser the first parameter

Tags: parameters, lua

As far as I see when my browser opens, it only get's the first param (hi). Thanks

```
os.execute("start http://www.MyWebsite.com?id=hi&name=cool")
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: use `os.execute("start http://www.MyWebsite.com?id=hi^&name=cool")`

os.execute passes your request to the system command interpreter, which you seem to realize because you used the 'start' command. In the Windows command interpreter, `&` is the command separator, so you're really executing two separate commands:

1. `start http://www.MyWebsite.com?id=hi`
2. `name=cool`

To stop Windows from interpreting `&` as the command separator, you need to escape it with `^`.